# Error connecting android to SQL

Tags: android

Iam writing an app which should communicate with a MySQL database. Ive added the driver class mysql..*.jar successfully to the project and it is loaded too. But if i try a connection to the databse i get the following error:

```
10-09 21:01:01.626  27334-27334/dd.edope.quizmasters D/libc﹕ [NET] getaddrinfo hostname mysql.1freehosting.com, servname NULL, ai_family 0
```

10-09 21:01:01.626  27334-27334/dd.edope.quizmasters W/System.err﹕

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.

Here my code:

```
private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://mysql.1freehosting.com/u741539452_quiz";
private static final String user = "....";
private static final String pass = "....";

public void testDB() {
    TextView tv = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.question);
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
    /* System.out.println("Database connection success"); */

        String result = "Database connection success\n";
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from Frage");
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

        //while(rs.next()) {
        //    result += rsmd.getColumnName(1) + ": " + rs.getInt(1) + "\n";
        //    result += rsmd.getColumnName(2) + ": " + rs.getString(2) + "\n";
        //    result += rsmd.getColumnName(3) + ": " + rs.getString(3) + "\n";
        //}
        tv.setText(result);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        tv.setText(e.toString());
    }

}
```

Could it be a wrong url to the database? On the Homepage of 1freehosting.com is said that the host adress is "mysql.1freehosting.com" but iam not sure if it is the right url for the db connection.

Any Ideas to handle? 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Most probable you can't access this database from remote. You can only access it by a script running on that server. If that's the case you can create a webservice which makes the database queries. Your app then makes HTTP requests to that service.

Comment: what is the reason for not accessing it with remote? My assumption is that the url to the database is the wrong but i dont know where to verify its correctness.

Comment: It's accessible locally only because of security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Create a java project in Eclipse

create package Name `com.example.sql`

Include `mysqlconnector.jar` in your project

```
package com.example.sql;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class JDBCExample {
    public static Connection con;

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        try
        {
            connectionQuery();

            PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("SELECT * from table_name");/*write query inside of prepared statement*/
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
            System.out.println("DataBase table accessed");

            while(result.next())
            {
               String retrievedid= result.getString("Column_name");

               System.out.println(retrievedid);
            }


            con.close();
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage().toString());
        }
  }

  public static void connectionQuery()
  {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/boopathi","root","root");
            System.out.println("Remote DB connection established");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Remote server could not be connected");
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Remote server could not be connected");
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Remote db connection establishment error");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("False query");
        }
    }
}
```

Above code for local accessing, if want to access public server use below link

[Refer this link for get to know how to write a service](http://avilyne.com/?p=105)